django DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS not working after upgrading to django 5.0
I just upgraded to django 5.0, and the DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS is no longer working in the settings.py file. It is not accepting DOY (%j) dates like it did before. I have looked at similar questions on stackoverflow, and I see that USE_L10N is deprecated and USE_L18N should be disabled. Even with these updates, it seems to be ignoring the DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS.
Ideas?
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

DATETIME_FORMAT = 'Y-z H:i:s'

USE_I18N = False

USE_TZ = False

DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = [
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
    '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f',
    '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S',
    '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M',
    '%Y-%m-%d',
    '%Y-%j %H:%M:%S.%f', 
    '%Y-%j %H:%M:%S', 
    '%Y-%j %H:%M', 
    '%Y-%jT%H:%M:%S.%f', 
    '%Y-%jT%H:%M:%S', 
    '%Y-%jT%H:%M', 
]


Date formatting settings is change in Django5 and you can follow these steps.
I'm not a senior developer, so, I hope it will useful for you.
I think the DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS should same as this:
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%Y-%j %H:%M:%S',]

In forms.py:
forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%Y-%j %H:%M:%S'])

In your template, use this template tag:
|date:"Y-z H:i:s"


Maybe this is what Richie suggested but here is how I worked around this issue. I didn't have to make any updates in templates. Still puzzled why the DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS variable in settings.py appears to be ignored after upgrading to django 5? Why do I need this workaround? It means I have to make the update in multiple places, which is unfortunate.
In any case... Here is how I worked around the issue. In a new file called custom_fields.py, I created a custom datetime field that inherits DateTimeField but updates the input_formats:
class CustomDateTimeField(forms.DateTimeField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomDateTimeField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.input_formats=[
            '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',
            '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
            '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
            '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f',
            '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S',
            '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M',
            '%Y-%m-%d',
            '%Y-%j %H:%M:%S.%f', 
            '%Y-%j %H:%M:%S', 
            '%Y-%j %H:%M', 
            '%Y-%jT%H:%M:%S.%f', 
            '%Y-%jT%H:%M:%S', 
            '%Y-%jT%H:%M', 
        ]

which I then use it in forms.py
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    start_time = custom_fields.CustomDateTimeField()

This allows me to enter a datetime in any of the listed formats (including DOY, %j).
